# Cannot SSH tunnel with PuTTY (Windows Vista) to connect to MySQL on a Linux box

Tags: mysql, putty, ssh-tunnel, database

Goal:

I am trying to copy a database onto my local box running Windows Vista.

Setup:

- Using MySQL 5.1 (mysql-essential-5.1win32) on Windows Vista
- On Linux box: MySQL  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.51a,
- I set up SSH tunneling on PuTTY this way:

  - Source port 3306,  Destination:localhost:3307
  - I am using 3307, because I have my own database on Windows Vista running on 3306

I can locally log in to the database on my Linux box
however, when I tried to login from MySQL administrator using

- Server Host: 127.0.0.1 Port 3307
- username:someUser
- password:somepassword

it failed with this message: MySQL Error Number 2003
Can't connect to MySQL server on 127,0.0.1 (10061)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you've got it "backwards".  The destination is not your loopback, it's the remote machine on the other network.  That, or you're using Remote instead of Local for the tunnel.

Try flipping the IP addresses around, example:

```
putty.exe -L 3307:mysql.yourdomain.com:3306
```

Where mysql.yourdomain.com is the name of the host that has the MySQL service you're trying to contact.  When putty pops up the connection dialog, put in the address, connect, and log in.  Then connect to localhost:3307 using the Administrator tool.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried with Windows 7 and it does not work for me either. The port will be forwarded, but not remapped. It will be still `localhost:3306`, which collides with the local server in your case. The PuTTY documentation also says that this would be the right way, but maybe the new security model of Windows Vista blocks the remapping of the ports.

I'd suggest, if you are using port 3306 locally, not to tunnel to *localhost* (which is normally mapped to `127.0.0.1`), but to tunnel to another IP address in your loopback range (maybe `127.0.0.2`). If your local SQL server is configured well, it only listens to `127.0.0.1:3306`, your remote tunnelled SQL server can listen on `127.0.0.2:3306`, so a remapping of the port is not necessary.

Comment: Not necessary - just tell PuTTy to bind the forward to local port 3307.

Comment: Have you ever tried? It does not work for me in Windows 7.

Comment: Did you follow the correction by Avery?

Comment: Yes, you're right, its vice versa.

Comment: Putty ssh tunnel doesn't work on my 64bit Windows 7, I tried SSH in git bash (Windows Git) and it worked beautifully! Fix it please putty!

http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/

Answer (score 1):

You don't want or need PuTTY for remote access to the database.

If you have permissions to connect to the remote database from your local machine, you can just use `mysqldump --host=remotemachine --user=remotesqluser --password=remotepassword --databases databasename>database.dump` on Vista, then load it onto your local box with `mysql --port=3307 --host=127.0.0.1 --user=localsqluser --password=localpassword <database.dump` - if you were running Linux locally I'd just pipe one program into the other, but I don't know if Vista's cmd.exe supports that.

If you *can't* connect remotely, but have administrator access to the Linux database, you can give yourself permissions (at the remote MySQL command line) with `grant select on databasename.* to 'remotesqluser'@'yourexternalIPaddress' identified by 'remotepassword';` (I think `select` is all you need). Once you have access, you can copy the database as above. Use `revoke` to lose the privileges when you've finished.

If you can't do any of this, you *will* need PuTTY: Connect to the Linux box and run the `mysqldump` command there (with `--host=127.0.0.1`). Copy the dump file to your Windows Vista machine by whatever means you like - SCP, FTP, and HTTP if you have a handy web server - and then you can load the database locally as above. Don't forget to delete the dump file on the Linux box after you're done.

**NOTE** if your mysqldump options aren't set up sensibly, you'll probably want to add `--extended-insert` to the command to speed things up (allows usage of multi-row inserts), and if there are any stored procedures in the database to transfer, `--routines` as well.

Comment: MySQL connections aren't encrypted unless you explicitly setup SSL and generally there's not often a good reason to have MySQL listening for the world. Unless you're utilising a VPN, it's far far safer to wrap the connection in an SSH tunnel.

Comment: I wanted to set up the db using navicat on my local machine. So I  need to copy the tables/data from the server  to my local machine. Port 3306 on the server is blocked, so I  was trying to set up an ssh tunnel (using Putty) and connect via that.

Comment: You can have Navicat setup the tunnel itself. I wouldn't necessarily advise using it to copy data though. Pete is right on account of using `mysqldump`.

Comment: We're hardened to having 3306 open to specific addresses - separate DB server from web server, and a replication loop that includes our dev server here in the office - but in this case, I agree that an ssh tunnel would be the best solution. I haven't had to use putty outside my phone for over a decade though, so can't advise on the incantation required!