# Accessing Mysql Database through ssh tunnel in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008-r2, odbc

I've had a look around for an answer to this online without much luck. I want to connect a MYSQL Database to SQL Server Management Studios through a ssh tunnel ODBC connection. I have usernames & passwords for this (ssh passwords and mysql passwords) and a ftp address however I'm not sure how to start this.

I have a putty client, should I open that and access the ftp address to set up port forwarding first, then go to step up the odbc mysql driver? Which passwords(mysql or ssh) should be used in each section?

Thanks for the help,

Mark

Comment: Establish network connectivity first (ssh port forwarding, using your ssh credentials), then configure your ODBC connection (using your SQL credentials). I'm not sure why you think FTP has anything to do with this - it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to use SQL Server Management Studios installed on your computer.

You should use putty to connect to your server using ssh, after setting up a tunnel where you forward server's 3306 port to your machine.

As for the tunnel, check the answers here: [cannot SSH tunnel with PuTTY (windows vista) to connect to mysql on the linux box](https://serverfault.com/questions/46285/cannot-ssh-tunnel-with-putty-windows-vista-to-connect-to-mysql-on-the-linux-bo)

After you're connected in ssh with putty and you have your tunnel setup, you can open SQL Server Management Studio and connect to your forwarded IP:PORT using MySQL's  account.

Comment: Thanks for that, another question is how do I set up the connection in SQL Server? Will I be setting up a linked server in sql server management studios to access this data?

Comment: I think this is a topic for another question. And on SQL server i'm not experienced anyway